# mysql sorting by day with WHERE also

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table called logs which has a date field as well as a column called success which is a tinyint(0), if it is 1 it means it was successful but if it was 0 it means it has failed.

I am trying to break my logs down into daily totals, so I want to work out on each day how many were successful and how many failed.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DAY( DATE ) , 
COUNT( * ) FROM logs 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2015-03-01','%Y-%m-%d' )  AND NOW() 
GROUP BY DAY( DATE )
```

This brings back the totals like this:

```
array(2) { ["DAY( DATE )"]=> string(2) "18" ["COUNT( * )"]=> string(3) 
"339" } 
array(2) { ["DAY( DATE )"]=> string(2) "20" ["COUNT( * )"]=> string(3) "161" } 

array(2) { ["DAY( DATE )"]=> string(2) "21" ["COUNT( * )"]=> string(2) "49" } 

array(2) { ["DAY( DATE )"]=> string(2) "22" ["COUNT( * )"]=> string(2) "72" }
```

So it shows me the totals on each day, however I want to be able to get the total successes and fails from the "success" column too. Is this possible within the same query or would I need to run another query with a `WHERE success=0` and `success=1` to get that information?

Comment: Thanks for the edit on the arrays!

Comment: The `str_to_date()` is unnecessary.  MySQL understands `'2015-03-01'`, or if you want to be more pedantic, `date('2015-03-01')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional sum as

```
SELECT DAY( DATE ) , 
sum(success = 1) as `success`,
sum(success = 0) as failure,
COUNT( * ) FROM logs 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2015-03-01','%Y-%m-%d' )  AND NOW() 
GROUP BY DAY( DATE )
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, is there a way to return the full date rather than just the day number do you know?

Comment: Yes but the you need to use that in the group by as well, something as `date(date)` and same in group by.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` within `SUM`:

```
SELECT DAY( DATE )
     , COUNT( * ) AS total_count
     , SUM(CASE WHEN success = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS failed_count
     , SUM(CASE WHEN success = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS succeeded_count
FROM logs 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2015-03-01','%Y-%m-%d' )  AND NOW() 
GROUP BY DAY( DATE )
```